# cannot Enable SPI Peripheral of AT91SAM7S256

Tags: embedded, arm

I am writing a code to interface micro SD card with AT91SAM7S ARM core, while debugging I had found that everything is right but the module cannot running as the enable bit is not set however i did it multi-times.

void SPI_Configure(AT91S_SPI *spi,
                          unsigned int id,
                          unsigned int configuration)
{

```
 // Disable the interrupt first
AT91C_BASE_AIC->AIC_IDCR = 1 << id;   
// Clear interrupt
AT91C_BASE_AIC->AIC_ICCR = 1 << id;

AT91C_BASE_PMC->PMC_PCER = 1 << id;
// Execute a software reset of the SPI twice
spi->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SWRST ;
spi->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SWRST | AT91C_SPI_SPIEN;
spi->SPI_MR = configuration;

// Disables the transmitter PDC transfer requests.
spi->SPI_PTCR = AT91C_PDC_RXTDIS | AT91C_PDC_TXTDIS;

spi->SPI_CR |= AT91C_SPI_SPIEN;
```

}

any one has any idea that may help me to solve this problem
thanks at all

Comment: Pick a peripheral register that is both readable and writable, e.g. SPI_CSR0.  Set up the register, then read the contents of that register.  If the contents are not what you wrote, then the peripheral is "dead".  Check if the peripheral's clock has been enabled.  BTW where is your code to setup the SPI_CSRn register?

Comment: `spi->SPI_CR |= AT91C_SPI_SPIEN;` -- The CR register is write-only.  The read value is undefined, so this statement is a bug that makes an assignment using an unknown value.  `spi->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SWRST | AT91C_SPI_SPIEN;` -- From experience, I avoid setting more than one operation at a time in a control register unless there is a compelling need and documented validity.

Comment: Did you enable the clock for the peripheral?